# Draw border around Gnuplot points

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting point using Gnuplot as explained in [this article](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-single-points/). For example:

[image: point plot example]

However I want to draw a black border around each of the points. In the above example, the square, circle, and triangle should have a black outline.

My line definitions look like this:

```
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#ebac23' pointtype 5 pointsize 2
```

But these definitions do not seem to take a `border` option. What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a border option. As a workaround, you could plot the points twice. The first time with black shapes and the second time with slightly smaller shapes of the colour you want.

```
unset key

set xrange [0.6:3.4]
set yrange [0:3]

# Square
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#000000' pointtype 5 pointsize 3
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#ebac23' pointtype 5 pointsize 2

# Circle
set style line 3 linecolor rgb '#000000' pointtype 7 pointsize 3
set style line 4 linecolor rgb '#ebac23' pointtype 7 pointsize 2

# Triangle
set style line 5 linecolor rgb '#000000' pointtype 9 pointsize 3
set style line 6 linecolor rgb '#ebac23' pointtype 9 pointsize 2

plot "<echo '1 2'"   with points ls 1, \
     ""              with points ls 2, \
     "<echo '2 1'"   with points ls 3, \
     ""              with points ls 4, \
     "<echo '3 1.5'" with points ls 5, \
     ""              with points ls 6
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the triangle doesn't look quite right. It seems the centre of the two triangles are not perfectly aligned. Still, maybe this is good enough. If not, you could try the diamond or pentagon shapes since they both look better.

Answer (score 0):

You can "misuse" `boxxyerrorbars` for this, but you will need to repeat the data. In the following I have repeated the data just as one block. `boxxyerrorbars` needs 4 numbers, the x,y position and a width and height. These need to be chosen to match the data scale in each direction.

```
set xrange [0:3.5]
set yrange [0:3]
set style line 1 linecolor rgb 'blue' pointtype 5 pointsize 2
set style line 2 linecolor rgb 'blue' pointtype 7 pointsize 2
set style line 3 linecolor rgb 'blue' pointtype 9 pointsize 2
plot '-' w p ls 1 notitle, \
 '-' w p ls 2 notitle,  \
 '-' w p ls 3 notitle, \
 '-' using 1:2:(.08):(.1) with boxxyerrorbars black notitle
1 2
e
2 1
e
3 1.5
e
1 2
2 1
3 1.5
e
```

[image: gnuplot image]